# Referencing global libraries from an ember component

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am using [ember-remarkable](https://github.com/johnotander/ember-remarkable) because I want to add both markdown parsing and syntax highlighting to my project.  The only thing it's missing is line numbers, which I want to add by using this library: [highlightjs-line-numbers.js](https://github.com/wcoder/highlightjs-line-numbers.js/)

I override `ember-remarkable`'s `md-text` component with the following:

```
import MDTextComponent from 'ember-remarkable/components/md-text';

export default MDTextComponent.extend({
  tagName: null,

  didRender() {
    this._super(...arguments);

    this.$("code[class*='language-']").each((i, block) => {
      this.$(block).addClass('hljs');
      hljs.lineNumbersBlock(block);
    });
  }
});
```

**Everything works**!  However, my editor complains that `hljs` is not defined, even though it is available on the page.

How do I avoid this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is ES6 modules, just import it. Otherwise you can use it as `window.hljs`.

When you run your js code in browser, `window` is the root of the global variables. So you can access it as `window.hljs`.

If you run your code in Fastboot, this should be a better way to access global objects: `(window || Fastboot || global).hljs`.

On the other hand, instead of using the global object container, you can just prevent linter to give this error. For eslint, see this configuration: [Specifying Globals](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals).

Answer (score 1):

You should explicitly import your dependencies, if for no other reason than to communicate to future readers. `import hljs from 'highlightjs-line-numbers'`